# Controller undefinded in angular despite proper wiring

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the following error:

```
  Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=NavigationController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:6:416
at Nb (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:19:417)
at ob (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:20:1)
at http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:75:177
at http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:57:112
at r (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:7:408)
at I (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:56:496)
at g (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:51:299)
at g (http://localhost:59838/bundles/angular?v=eGVVmShKFZLix9VnkpB8psikEOhD8WAVwpsLlHRCbyE1:51:316)
```

Here is my app.js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', ['navigation']);
})();
```

here is the navigation controller:

```
function() {
var navigation = angular.module('navigation', []);
    navigation.controller('NavigationController', function () {
    this.tabs = [
        { title: 'First Tab', content: 'Controllers\FirstTab' },
    ];
    });
})();
```

And here is the partial view that renders this: (It is currently not getting here)

```
 <div ng-controller="NavigationController as nav">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="tab in nav.tabs">{{tab.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To me (a noob in angular) everything looks good. What am I missing?

UPDATE:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkdmgqf0/)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: it works here:http://jsbin.com/bavesopoju/1/edit?console. maybe your iife are causing the functions to live in different scopes.

Comment: @Avraam added a fiddle.

Comment: @cbass suggestions on how to debug my iife?

Comment: @Robert check if this is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/nkdmgqf0/1/ and I will add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this:

```js
var navigation = angular.module('navigation', []);

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['navigation']);


navigation.controller('NavigationController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.tabs = [
        { title: 'First Tab', content: 'Controllers\FirstTab' },
        { title: 'Second Tab', content: 'Controllers\SecondTab' },
        { title: 'Third Tab', content: 'Controllers\ThirdTab' },
        { title: 'Fourth Tab', content: 'Controllers\FourthTab' },
        { title: 'Fifth Tab', content: 'Controllers\FifthTab' },
        { title: 'Sixth Tab', content: 'Controllers\SixthTab' },
        { title: 'Seventh Tab', content: 'Controllers\SeventhTab' }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="NavigationController as nav">
        <div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
            <b> {{ tab.title}} </b> {{ tab.content}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```